# IntelliJ | How to check out specific branch

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Recently I started development in IntelliJ with Git. 
I am trying to check out one specific remote branch only. But while checking out source code, IntelliJ never asked for which branch you want to check out. And by default, it checked out master branch only.
Once the master branch is checked out then I can switch to my specific branch.

I searched IntelliJ documentation about how to check out specific branch or give the intial branch name to check out like eclipse but not able to locate it.

So can someone please help me about how to check out specific branch only using IntelliJ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this on the command line, but IntelliJ can't help with this. On the command line you want to use this template:

```
git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch <folder>
```

Replacing url, branch, and folder, as appropriate

Answer (score 2):

You should find a "git" tabon the bottom left of your IDE. There, you can find the different branches. if you right click on the branch you want to check out a pop-up menu appears with a "checkout" option" displayed

[image]

Comment: flawless answer!

Answer (score -2):

Check out [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/checking-out-switching-between-branches.html) documentation page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already went through this documentation and it talks about switching branches once you check out initial. At the time of initial check out, it always goes to the master only, I want to change to specific branch only.